# Update kde to newest version

Tags: debian, kde, upgrade

My OS is debian squeeze and I installed kde as graphical interface. My current kde version is 4.4.5. But I want to update it to the newest version (4.10.5). How to do it?

Comment: So this is what you actually wanted to *accomplish* when you asked about [upgrading Debian from squeeze to sid](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/87312/2465)?

Comment: Yes.. as I said I am a newbie^^

Answer (score 1):

According to the [packages list](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=kde) 4.10.5 havent made into Squeeze yet. But is avaliable in Sid. You can add Sid packages to your sources.list and install the packages from there. The problem is KDE uses a whole bunch of libs which *might* break when combined with your current setup. As squeeze is really "old" I'm not sure they will backport kde 4.10 to it. According to [here](http://pkg-kde.alioth.debian.org/):
August 24, 2010
As Squeeze has been frozen, Debian will ship Squeeze with KDE 4.4.5. Unstable repos will have 4.4.5 too until Squeeze release. KDE 4.5.x will be available via other repo some time later.

Seems 4.10 wont make into your release. Hence I suggest you to dist-upgrade.

Comment: I followed this tutorial (digitalocean.com/community/articles/upgrading-debian-to-unstable) to upgrade squeeze to sid. The problem is that I didn't get any questions to answer during dist-upgrade (like he said) and after repeating dist-upgrade I get these errors:
E: Couldn't get lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock - open (11: The ressource isn't available)
E: The directory /var/cache/apt/archives/ can't get locked ..
My sources.list:

deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian sid main

deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian squeeze main

deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian sid main contrib non-free

Comment: Have you ran the update till the end? Was it successful?

Comment: I don't really know.. I got a really big changelog and didn't saw any errors. Atm KDE still reminds me of 214 updates.. but dist-upgrade isn't working as I said.